# How feof() works in C

Tags: c, file-handling, feof

Does feof() checks for eof for the current position of filepointer or checks for the position next to current filepointer?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Every `FILE` stream has an internal flag that indicates whether the caller has tried to read past the end of the file already. `feof` returns that flag. The flag does not indicate whether the current file position is as the end of the file, only whether a previous read has tried to read past the end of the file.

As an example, let's walk through what happens, when reading through a file containing two bytes.

```
f = fopen(filename, "r"); // file is opened
assert(!feof(f));         // eof flag is not set
c1 = getc(f);             // read first byte, one byte remaining
assert(!feof(f));         // eof flag is not set
c2 = getc(f);             // read second byte, no bytes remaining
assert(!feof(f));         // eof flag is not set
c3 = getc(f);             // try to read past end of the file
assert(feof(f));          // now, eof flag is set
```

This is why the following is the **wrong** way to use eof when reading through a file:

```
f = fopen(filename, "r");
while (!feof(f)) {
    c = getc(f);
    putchar(c);
}
```

Because of the way `feof` works, the end-of-file flag is only set once `getc`
tries to read past the end of the file. `getc` will then return `EOF`, which is
not a character, and the loop construction causes `putchar` to try to write it
out, resulting in an error or garbage output.

Every C standard library input method returns an indication of success or
failure: `getc` returns the special value `EOF` if it tried to read past the
end of the file, or if there was an error while reading. The special value is
the same for end-of-file and error, and this is where the proper way to use
`feof` comes in: you can use it to distinguish between end-of-file and error
situations.

```
f = fopen(filename, "r");
c = getc(f);
if (c == EOF) {
    if (feof(f))
        printf("it was end-of-file\n");
    else
        printf("it was error\n");
}
```

There is another internal flag for `FILE` objects for error situations:
`ferror`. It is often clearer to test for errors instead of "not end of file".
An idiomatic way to read through a file in C is like this:

```
f = fopen(filename, "r");
while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
}
if (ferror(f)) {
    perror(filename):
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
fclose(f);
```

(Some error checking has been elided from examples here, for brevity.)

The `feof` function is fairly rarely useful.

Comment: Sorry, got excited and expanded it a bit.

Comment: FILE *f,*g;
    int c1,c2,c3;
    f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    g=fopen("t.txt","w");
    c1 = getc(f);   
    printf("%d\n",c1);
    putc(c1,g);
    c2 = getc(f);         
    printf("%d\n",c2);
    putc(c2,g);
    c3 = getc(f);
    printf("%d\n",c3);
    putc(c3,g);

    return 0;

Comment: tried this code but didn't get any garbage value or error.. Why is this so

Comment: Alfred, I get a garbage byte as the third and last byte in t.txt. Is your test.txt really two bytes long, and not three bytes? (use 'echo -n 12 > test.txt' in Unix to create test.txt, and note the -n option).

Comment: Herber Shildt recommends in his books to use the function the wrong way instead of EOF.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a better understanding of how `feof` works, by knowing how it's implemented.  Here is a simplified version of how the 7th Edition Unix stdio library implements `feof`.   Modern libraries are very similar, adding code offering thread-safety, increased efficiency, and a cleaner implementation.

```
extern  struct  _iobuf {
    char    *_ptr;
    int     _cnt;
    char    *_base;
    char    _flag;
    char    _file;
} _iob[_NFILE];

#define _IOEOF  020

#define feof(p)         (((p)->_flag&_IOEOF)!=0)

#define getc(p)         (--(p)->_cnt>=0? *(p)->_ptr++&0377:_filbuf(p))

int
_filbuf(FILE *iop)
{

    iop->_ptr = iop->_base;
    iop->_cnt = read(fileno(iop), iop->_ptr, BUFSIZ);
    if (iop->_cnt == 0) {
            iop->_flag |= _IOEOF;
            return(EOF);
    }
    return(*iop->_ptr++ & 0377);
```

}

The stdio library maintains with each file a structure containing an internal buffer pointed by `_base`.  The current character in the buffer is pointed by `_ptr` and the number of characters available is contained in `_cnt`.  The `getc` macro, which is the base for a lot of higher-level functionality, like `scanf`,  tries to return a character from the buffer.  If the buffer is empty, it will call `_filbuf` to fill it.  `_filbuf` in turn will call `read`.  If `read` returns 0, which means that no more data is available, `_filbuf` will set the `_IOEOF` flag, which `feof` checks each time you call it to return true.

As you can understand from the above, `feof` will return true the first time you try to read a character past the end of the file (or a library function tries in your behalf).  This has subtle implications on the behavior of various functions.  Consider a file containing a single character: the digit `1`.  After you read that character with `getc`, `feof` will return false, because the `_IOEOF` flag is unset; nobody has yet tried to read past the end of the file.  Calling `getc` again will result in a call to `read`, the setting of the `_IOEOF` flag, and this will cause `feof` to return true.  However, after reading the number from the same file using `fscanf("%d", &n)`, `feof` will immediately return true, because `fscanf` will have tried to read additional digits of the integer.