# Storing words from text file into char array using feof

Tags: c, arrays, text, storage

So I have a textfile which goes like this:

zero three two one five zero zero five seven .. etc

and there is a lot of it, 9054 words to be exact

My idea was to create a char array of 9054 spaces and store it in, this is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char tmp;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char array[44000];

FILE *in_file;

in_file = fopen("in.txt", "r");

// Read file in to array
while (!feof(in_file))
{
      fscanf(in_file,"%c",&tmp);
      array[i] = tmp;
      i++;
}

// Display array
while (j<i)
{
      printf("%c",array[j]);
      j++;
}


fclose(in_file);

while(1);
return 0;
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to store words, because from what I have done stores each character into the array so it becomes an array of around 44000. How can I make it so the array holds words instead?

Also I don't have an idea what the feof function does, especially the line

```
while (!feof(in_file))
```

what does this line exactly mean? Sorry I am still in the baby stages of learning C, I tried looking up what feof does but there is not much to find

Comment: you are creating an array of chars but should create an array (or better: list) of strings. And for starters have a look at this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337614/how-feof-works-in-c

Comment: For your code you're saying, *...this is what I've done so far*, and then you are saying, *Also I don't have any idea what the feof function does...* and are using `feof`. If you wrote the code, why are you using `feof` if you don't know what it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rather than check `feof()`, which tells you if the end-of-file occurred in the *previous* input operation, check the result of `fscanf()`
2. Reads "words" with `"%s"` and limit the max numbers of `char` to be read.

   ```
   char buf[100];
   fscanf(in_file,"%99s",buf);
   ```

Putting that together:

```
    #define WORD_SIZE_MAX 20
    #define WORD_COUNT_MAX 10000

    char array[WORD_COUNT_MAX][WORD_SIZE_MAX];
    unsigned word_i = 0;

    for (i=0; i<WORD_COUNT_MAX; i++) {
      if (fscanf(in_file,"%19s", word_list[i]) != 1) {
        break;
      }
    }
```

---

Another approach is to use OP code nearly as is.  Read the whole file into 1 array.  Then on printing, skip white-space.

Comment: hello thanks for the reply, what do you mean by reads words with %s?

Comment: and why am i creating an array with rows and columns(wordcountmax and wordsizemax)? please help!

Comment: @anony Each `word_list[i]` stores 1 word with up to `WORD_SIZE_MAX-1` characters.  The fixed sized `array[][]` supports up to `WORD_COUNT_MAX` words.  Other approaches exist involving memory management (`malloc()/free()`.  I thought this would be simplest for you to code and use.

Comment: i mean, the numbers in my textfile max' characters a word could have is 5. (seven, three, eight). so would the word_size_max be 5 for me? i tried using your code but it is too confusing for me :/ which file exactly in your code does the scanning words into array business?

Comment: @anony  The above comment "... with up to `WORD_SIZE_MAX-1` characters." implies that if the longest word is 5 characters, then `WORD_SIZE_MAX` needs to be _at least_ 6.  In this answer `infile` is the `FILE` pointer, used just like in your post.  The `fscanf()` performs the scanning.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/5gde8 this is my code.. i think i confused myself with it :/

Comment: after a lot of time looking at this, i think i've finally figured it out, thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @anony  Ref code should be `if (fscanf(in_file,"%5s", array[i]) != 1) {`  5 not 19 as you have `char array[45000][6];` and not `char array[45000][20];`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you may use the following steps:

- Dump the whole text file to a char buffer.
- Use `strtok` to split the char buffer to multiple tokens or words.
- Use an array of pointer to char to store individual words.

Something along this line would do. Note, I use your question title as the text file. You will need to replace `20` as appropriately.

```
    int main ()
    {
        FILE *in_file;
        in_file = fopen("in.txt", "r");
        fseek( in_file, 0, SEEK_END );
        long fsize = ftell( in_file );
        fseek( in_file, 0, SEEK_SET );

        char *buf = malloc( fsize + 1 );
        fread( buf, fsize, 1, in_file ); // Dump the whole file to a char buffer.
        fclose( in_file );

        char *items[20] = { NULL };
        char *pch;

        pch = strtok (buf," \t\n");
        int i = 0;
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            items[i++] = pch;
            pch = strtok (NULL, " \t\n");
        }

        for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            if( items[i] != NULL )
            {
                printf( "items[%d] = %s\n", i, items[i] );
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

Output:

```
items[0] = Storing
items[1] = words
items[2] = from
items[3] = textfile
items[4] = into
items[5] = char
items[6] = array
items[7] = using
items[8] = feof?
```