# Cant read file text file in C

Tags: c

Hello i got a problem im trying to solve problem and learn how the learning from files works .I  did this code by tutorial and when i execute instead of learning my file and write on console something like 1 4 6 5 1 etc.. its just spam only 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 and then repeat 
If you would say me where is the problem it will be good thanks for ur time :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define UNUSED(__ARG__) ((void)__ARG__)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    UNUSED(argc);
    UNUSED(argv);

    int i = 0;
    FILE* x =fopen("cisla.txt","r");
     fscanf(x,"%d",&i);
 while (!feof (x))
 {
     printf("%d",i);
     fscanf(x,"%d",&i);


 }
 fclose(x);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: NB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: while (!feof (x)) Is that right? Shouldn't it be eof? Also, does x need to be a pointer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337614/how-feof-works-in-c

Comment: @Millar248 You should probably take a step back and read a book or tutorial. Because yes it's right (but not correct) and yes it must be a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever tutorial this is, throw it out.

First, you need to check whether your file operations succeeded, otherwise the program will blindly continue along. Likely the `fopen` failed. It returns `NULL` on failure so you can check for that and get an error message with [`perror`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_perror.htm).

```
FILE *x = fopen("cisla.txt","r");
if( x == NULL ) {
    perror("Could not open the file");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then, as others have mentioned, [you don't check for end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Instead do the IO operation and check whether it succeeded or failed. In this case, `fscanf` returns the number of matched items which should be 1.

```
while ( fscanf(x, "%d", &i) == 1 ) {
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Note that [the `scanf` family is fraught with gotchas](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). But you'll get to them later.

Finally, that `UNUSED` stuff is very clever and totally unnecessary. Just declare `main` with no arguments. [This is perfectly valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146594/definition-of-main-in-c).

```
int main() {
```

Comment: @RábelDavid `fscanf(x, "%d", &i)` will only read integers. `while ( fscanf(x, "%d", &i) == 1 )` means the loop will stop once it sees something that is not an integer. What's in the file? Since you're just starting out it might be simpler to use [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) rather than `fscanf` and just read lines out of the file without trying to process them.

Comment: Oh then it will stop when i have space between numbers because it read space like \ ?
i would like to read text file which contains only numbers now cuz i want to get how it works .  Then in file is just this 94643134 nothing more already But still dont have idea why it writes on console Zav for no reason

Comment: @RábelDavid It will handle spaces for you. What is "console Zav"?

Comment: Oh ok nice . I dont have idea. When i execute its just write ZAV insted of my list

Comment: Im using QT creator :)

Comment: Ok i found the main problems first one Zav = End of program in QT 
And it works now but i have to use whole path like C:/Users/Rabeles/Desktop/ADS_1ukol/task1-master/input.txt 
If i use just "input.txt"  it doenst work it pass throught test and open file but then it didnt write anything.  do you have some ideas why? when it pass over the test if x==null?

Comment: @RábelDavid Without seeing your source code and having never used QT Creator, I can only guess. Opening `input.txt` will look for it in ***the directory where the program is run***. Since you're running the program via an IDE I don't know what directory that is. You can find out with [`getcwd`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/298510/14660). If you use an absolute path there is no ambiguity.